# Is there a similar research paper LaTeX template like this one?

Tags: pdftex

https://research.google/pubs/pub334/

[image]

Is there a similar research paper LaTeX template like this one shown above?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! See, where it is published. Publisher has "template" for article, which they publish.

Comment: Published in Computer Networks, (1998)  The editor is the same, but format might have changed. See elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions. And use `elsarticle.cls` in combination with BibTeX.